# abap sql / CDS- how to get multiple rows into a single row (group by)?

Tags: cds

My CDS view delivers a result like this.

```
* RESULT CDS VIEW
*----------------------------
*|CHARG|Z_F1  |Z_F2  |Z_F3  |
*----------------------------
*|011  |VAL F1|      |      |
*|011  |      |VAL F2|      |
*|011  |      |      |VAL F3|
*----------------------------
```

I want to achieve something like a MySQL `group_by` CHARG resulting in just 1 row like this:

```
* EXPECTED RESULT
*----------------------------
*|CHARG|Z_F1  |Z_F2  |Z_F3  |
*----------------------------
*|011  |VAL F1|VAL F2|VAL F3|
*----------------------------
```

How to do that in abap sql / cds views? It expects all the fields in the `group_by` clause.

I am looking for a CDS solution without abap coding.

---

I forgot to mention that the `Z_F1` to `Z_F3` fields are a pivot result of the same column, that's why they are in different rows at first place.

The cds looks like this:

```
... as select...{
charg,
case when _f1  = '1' then 'VAL F1' else '' end as Z_F1,
case when _f1  = '2' then 'VAL F2' else '' end as Z_F2,
case when _f1  = '3' then 'VAL F3' else '' end as Z_F3
...
}
```

Comment: The MySQL example is not needed because you clearly explain what you expect, and also I doubt a lot that MySQL does what you say.

Comment: @SandraRossi, I removed the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I finally found a way to merge multiple rows into one row in this article:

[Transpose Or Merge Multiple Rows In One Row CDS Views](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/07/16/transpose-or-merge-multiple-rows-in-one-row-cds-views/)

The solution is, as expected a `group_by` clause of just the 1 field all rows share.
You can use the SQL `MAX()` function to use group_by without the Z_F1 to 3 fields.

```
{
   charg,
   max( case when _f1  = '1' then 'VAL F1' end ) as Z_F1,
   max( case when _f1  = '2' then 'VAL F2' end ) as Z_F2,
   max( case when _f1  = '3' then 'VAL F3' end ) as Z_F3
}
group by charg
```

resulting in:

```
*----------------------------
*|CHARG|Z_F1  |Z_F2  |Z_F3  |
*----------------------------
*|011  |VAL F1|VAL F2|VAL F3|
*----------------------------
```